# Can't call all() built-in function in IronPython

Tags: asp.net, ironpython, built-in

I'm using the same test code in cPython and IronPython, in cPython it works but I'm getting
"name all is not defined" in IronPython in asp.net . I wonder if I have to import some module to use it in IronPython or it's just not available?

```
lista = ['a','b']
listados = ['a','b','c']

aca = all(value in listados for value in lista)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `all` and `any` functions were added in Python 2.5.  Are you using at least version 2.5 of IronPython?  If not, it's fairly easy to define a fallback version:

```
try: all
except NameError:
    def all(iterable):
        for value in iterable:
            if not value: return False
        return True
```

Answer (score 1):

What version of IronPython are you running?  all() is a fairly recent Python addition (2.5).